# Running xcode 4.3.3 project with xcode 4.5.2 in device.. (No issue in simulator)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5, xcode4.3

Actually **I have started my application in xcode 4.3.3** in 4 months back,

Now *our requirement is to run the app in* **iOS 6.0**

For that purpose **I upgraded my xcode to xcode 4.5.2 wich supports iOS 6.0.**

*those apps started in xcode 5.5.2 are executed in device without any issues.*

***`But those apps Started in Xcode 4.3.3 and bellow are not executed while im testing in Device (Any ios).`***

(no issues in simulator..)

I got Error  ***`"Apple Mach O Linker Error"`***

clang: ***error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)***

I have tried *`following steps, even I didn't run the app`*..

Disconnect your device.

1. Disconnect the device.
2. Quit xcode (Don't just simply close the window, quit it)
3. Delete derived data folder (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ gbrvhlvwmpiobxdujegtghggrffp - or something like that)
4. Now start Xcode, connect device and run the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just accidentally deleted a .m file, while .h was in the project. The

problem disappeared when I've restored the .m file. Also sometime the problem was that in

XCode 4, the dependencies do not assume the architecture settings of the main project, as

they previously did in XCode. I had to go through all of my dependencies setting them for

the correct architecture.

Comment: See these discussion & check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116427/apple-mach-o-linker-id-error & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329001/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-compiling-for-device

Comment: Check your all framework that you need...Sometimes required framework are missing...